# Issue with if Statement in C

Tags: c

I have the below code. I am looking to run it so that either the user is prompted for a letter and I will supply a name. I am getting only the first response when I run my code. Is there any reason why it isn't moving through each if statement individually to determine which was entered?

```
while(b > 40 && b < 50){
    char name;
    printf("Welcome to my name generator. Please enter the first letter of the name\n");
    scanf(" %c", &name);
    printf("Enter name (TDL): \n");
    if(scanf(" %c", &name) == T || t){
        printf("The name is Tom.\n");
    }
    if(scanf(" %c", &name) == D || d){
        printf("The name is Dan.\n");
    }
    if(scanf(" %c", &name) == L || l){
        printf("The name is Lucas.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Unknown Name.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `T`? What is `t`? What is `D`???? Why are you overwriting `name` over and over? `(a == b || c)` does not do what you think it does: hint ... `((a == b) || c)` ==> `(<0 or 1> || c)`

Comment: Why are you calling scanf repeatedly?

Comment: Please note `if (x() == A || B)` means if `x()==A` is non zero or `B` is non-zero

Comment: Just call `scanf()` once. Then test `if (tolower(name) == 't')`

Comment: If you want to compare with a character, you need to put the character in single quotes.

Comment: **Turn on and mind your compiler warnings.** The competent people who wrote your compiler made it emit those warnings to **help you**.

Comment: Too many errors. If is better to find them yourself and learn good lesson(s), not to ask for help. For example `else` is for the last `if` not for all.

Comment: There are so many basic errors here. You really need to study some syntax and documentation and go through tutorials or something.

Comment: The problem is your if statement conditions, for example you wrote ```if(scanf(" %c", &name) == T || t)``` the left side of the condition is fine but on the right side your just writing ```t``` which is just automatically ```1```, with this in mind your also using the ```OR``` operator which determines if ```A OR B``` is True, since ```t``` is ```1``` the whole if statement becomes true.

Answer (score 2):

The variable b is not getting updated in the while loop hence it is running the same loop again and again since the condition is being fulfilled. Increment or decrement b so that the while loop moves to the next character.